# Why does $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}$?

Tags: group-theory, inverse, normal-subgroups

I have read countless proofs that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of H but there is one step in the part about proving the inverse which I just cannot get my head around:

$(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}$

I just can't understand why it isn't:

$(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=g^{-1}h^{-1}(g^{-1})^{-1}$

Obviously there is something very fundamental/simple I don't understand so would appreciate if someone could explain this step to me.

Comment: Well, it might help to think: what is the inverse of "Door opens, a person walks through, then the door closes"?  Is it "Door closes, a person walks back through it, then the door opens"?  Or is it "Door opens, a person walks back through it, then the door closes"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let's multiply them!

\begin{align}
& \ \ \ \ \ (ghg^{-1})\cdot(g^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&= gh(g^{-1}(g^{-1})^{-1})h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&= gh(1)h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&= g(hh^{-1})g^{-1}\\
&= g(1)g^{-1}\\
&= gg^{-1}\\
&=1
\end{align}

So really, the inverse of $ghg^{-1}$ is $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}$.

Try multiplying $ghg^{-1}$ by what you thought the inverse was, $g^{-1}h^{-1}(g^{-1})^{-1}$, and you'll see the terms won't cancel, and the expression is not (necessarily) $1$.

Comment: The question is, of course, very simple, and there is no need to vote, but how can I correct the injustice and give my voice to a competitor, since his answer is better

Comment: That's what the voting system is for. Of course, there is no "better" answer, since that is completely subjective; however, people can vote on the answers based on whether or not it helped them. If my answer did not help you, then don't upvote it. If the other answer did, then upvote it. After all, upvotes don't really matter, since it should not significantly influence the OP's opinion on the answers, nor should it influence yours or anyone else's. The only thing it does is put my post higher, but that will be overwritten by the OP's accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should know the fact that

> For $a,b\in G$, $$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$

Otherwise, try to prove it.
So, $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=((gh)g^{-1})^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-1}(gh)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}$.